# Javascript false comparison even if the numbers are equal

Tags: javascript

i have this javascript code :

```js
var a = 0.1
var b = 0.7
var c = 0.8
console.log(a + b);
if (a + b == c) console.log("OK")
```

does not give the result as it should

the output is `0.7999999999999999` instead of `0.8` and never comes to the if statement

what is the problem here?

Comment: welcome to the wonderful world of floating point arithmetic.

Comment: Your number is loosing precision

Comment: This problem can be solved with a work around  multiply the two float number with 10 after performing your calculations, divide the answer with 10